# Trying to access mapped network drive files using installed service local system

Tags: windows, networking

I have installed a service which purpose is to listen incoming files in a mapped network drive. For now, it does not respond to any new incoming file in the mapped network drive.

The service is just a jar file which can be run using java -jar. When I run using java -jar, it works.

Does anyone have an idea what to do to make it work in a service way?

Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

Your service is most likely running under a different user account (probably the Local System Account) so it won't see the mapped drive.  Try running it under the same account as the logged-in user.

[image: Screenshot from the Services MMC Snap-in]